# Best way to model a wavy pattern for CNC milling process?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

Planning a CNC milling job of for a wavy pattern I want to use on the ceiling.

What is the best way to control the curvature for each wave blending into the next one? I would like to only build the "tip" of the wave and then control the curvature (the blend) on each side independently, maybe the same way you control curvature when editing vectors in Illustrator via a 'weight' parameter to manually sculpt each part.

[image: example wavy pattern]

Answer (score 2):

How's this for a starting point? I took a simple grid mesh and applied edge creases to every other row:

[image: Basic grid with creases]

...Scaled it down in one direction and then pulled the edges perpendicular to the creases up and down to build a crude series of parallel waves:

[image: Scaled grid with crude waves]

...Then added a subdivision modifier:

[image: Waves smoothed with subdivision modifier]

There's plenty of room for improvement, but using edges as control points made it relatively simple to sculpt a basic wavy shape without too much hassle.

Comment: slap a subsurf modifier on that.

Comment: @Mutant Bob: That's what the third image is, I just didn't turn it up very many steps since it was a quick illustration. Or is that what you meant?

Comment: *facepalm* the creases in your answer confused me.  When I looked at his original picture I didn't see any creases.